# How can I break out of telegram bot loop application.run_polling()?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

```
def bot_start():
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token("api_key").build()


    async def stop(update, context):
        await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='Terminating Bot...')
        await application.stop()
        await Updater.shutdown(application.bot)
        await application.shutdown()

    async def error(update, context):
        err = f"Update: {update}\nError: {context.error}"
        logging.error(err, exc_info=context.error)
        await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text=err)

   application.add_handler(CommandHandler('stop', stop))
   application.add_error_handler(error)

   application.run_polling()
```

I tried everything I could to stop it and I couldnt as it's not letting other lines of code that comes after calling bot_start() run. It basically never reaches them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Application.run_polling`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/latest/telegram.ext.application.html#telegram.ext.Application.run_polling) is a convenience methods that starts everything *and keeps the bot running until you signal the process to shut down*. It's mainly intended to be used if the `Application` is the only long-running thing in your python process. If you want to run other things alongside your bot, you can instead manually call the methods listed in the docs of `run_polling`. You may also want to have a look at [this example](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/latest/examples.html#examples-customwebhookbot), where this is showcased for a setup for a custom webhook server is used instead of PTBs built-in one.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Umm I'm kinda still stuck on how can i signal the run_polling to stop

Answer (score 1):

After searching through the documentation for version 20 of `python-telegram-bot`, I found out that using the `telegram.ext.Updater` class with an `asyncio.Queue` is the key to getting the telegram updates without blocking the main thread. The telegram application, the updater, and the queue should be initialized, and then one can use either `que.get()` asynchronously to wait for the next update or `que.get_nowait()` to get a new update instantaneously, which raises an exception if non are available.

```
import os
import asyncio
import telegram.ext

TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN = "ADD YOUR TOKEN HERE"

async def main():
    que = asyncio.Queue()
    application = telegram.ext.ApplicationBuilder().token(TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN).build()
    updater = telegram.ext.Updater(application.bot, update_queue=que)
    await updater.initialize()
    await updater.start_polling()
    
    # Option 1
    update = await que.get()
    
    # Option 2, replace option 1 if you like
    # update = que.get_nowait()
    
    print(update)

asyncio.run(main())
```