# MessageHandler not receiving messages when using Python Telegram Bot's "application.start()" API

Tags: python-telegram-bot

This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74484933/how-can-i-break-out-of-telegram-bot-loop-application-run-polling). However, I have tried the solution mentioned there and I am still facing the same issue.

I have a CCTV feed that I snap from, upon receiving an IFTTT message.
This works well when I'm using `application.run_polling()` method.
But I need the PTB part of the code to be stoppable in certain situations which I am not able to achieve, when I replace `run_polling()` with `start()` and `stop()` wrapping the other long-running code I have.

The problem is: I do not receive any messages in the `MessageHandler` that I'm using. The messages are received when I use `application.run_polling()` but not when I replace it with `application.start()`

NOTE1: I have referred to [this](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.updater.html#telegram.ext.Updater.update_queue) and [this](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/examples.customwebhookbot.html) to achieve following code, which is not working for me.

NOTE2: `telegram.ext.Updater` examples seen on SO or elsewhere on the web, are almost all from API v13 which do not run on v20 - something I found after extensive trial-and-error. I am assuming that `updater.dispatcher` questions are also out of context for

The relevant piece of code that DOESN'T work:

```
async def main() -> None:
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(C_TELEGRAM_LOGIN_TOKEN).build()
    chat_handler = MessageHandler(filters.ALL, on_chat)
    application.add_handler(chat_handler)
    print("Telegram bot initialized, will start polling now.")

    vid_read_thread = Thread(target=start_reading_frames)
    vid_read_thread.start()
    async with application:
        await application.initialize()
        await application.updater.initialize()
        await application.start()
        await application.updater.start_polling()
        print("called application.start()")
        ''' cv2's imread and imshow loop '''
        await application.updater.stop_polling()
        await application.stop()
```

And code that DOES work - but causing main-thread to be blocked by `run_polling`:

```
    vid_read_thread = Thread(target=start_reading_frames)

    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(C_TELEGRAM_LOGIN_TOKEN).build()
    chat_handler = MessageHandler(filters.ALL, on_chat)
    application.add_handler(chat_handler)
    vid_read_thread.start()
    application.run_polling()
```

Here is the full code for what I am running on.

- main1() is the function that I need to get to work. In this function I've tried to run `start_reading_frames` method with and without `threading.Thread`. When without the threading, it was in between `start_polling` and `stop`
- main2() is working currently but I want to get rid of it.

```
""" ----------- global variables ---------- """
vcap = None
is_video_capture_on = False
latest_frames = deque()
last_stored_frame_ts = -1
is_reading_frame_queue = False
"""
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)"""


def start_reading_frames():
    global vcap, latest_frames, last_stored_frame_ts, is_video_capture_on
    try:
        cv2.namedWindow(C_VIDEO_WINDOW_NAME, cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)
        while is_video_capture_on:
            if not vcap:
                ts_start = time.time()
                vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(C_RTSP_STREAM_URL)
                ts_end = time.time()
                time_taken_sec = ts_end - ts_start
                print(f"  start_reading_frames() Video capture started, time taken: {time_taken_sec}s")

            v_ret, v_frame = vcap.read()
            if v_ret:
                current_frame_ts = time.time()
                time_diff = current_frame_ts - last_stored_frame_ts
                if not is_reading_frame_queue and (last_stored_frame_ts < 0 or time_diff > C_MINIMUM_DURATION_BETWEEN_FRAMES_SEC):
                    latest_frames.appendleft(v_frame)
                    last_stored_frame_ts = time.time()
                    while len(latest_frames) > C_MAX_FRAMES_TO_STORE:
                        latest_frames.pop()
                else:
                    # we want to skip this frame until we get a new frame AFTER the minimum duration is reached
                    pass
                # end of if, now we can render that frame
                cv2.imshow(C_VIDEO_WINDOW_NAME, v_frame)
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    print("  start_reading_frames() Got 'q' command - bot will stop now.")
                    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            else:
                vcap = None

            del v_frame
        # end while is_video_capture_on
        print("  start_reading_frames() Out of while is_video_capture_on")
    except Exception as e3:
        print("  start_reading_frames() EXC:" + str(e3))
    print(" start_reading_frames() EXIT")


async def on_chat(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    global is_reading_frame_queue
    print("  on_chat() ENTER | channel_post:" + str(update.channel_post))
    try:
        msg_og = str(update.channel_post.text)
        msg_up = msg_og.strip().upper()
        if any(s in msg_up for s in C_SNAP_TRIGGERS):
            img_name = datetime.now().strftime(C_DATETIME_FORMAT) + ".jpg"
            img_path = os.path.join(C_IMG_DIR_PATH, img_name)
            out_imgs = []

            # let's catch 2 extra frames
            time.sleep(C_MINIMUM_DURATION_BETWEEN_FRAMES_SEC * 2)

            # now stop catching any extra frames
            is_reading_frame_queue = True

            # whatever is in the queue by now, let's create a collage from it
            for i in range(0, len(latest_frames)):
                out_imgs.append(latest_frames.pop())

            # Resume filling in the queue
            is_reading_frame_queue = False

            # Create collage and dump into filesystem
            out_img = cv2.vconcat(out_imgs)
            wr_sts = cv2.imwrite(img_path, out_img)
            print(f"  on_chat() Image write sts:{wr_sts}, path:{img_path} | buffer length:{len(latest_frames)}")

            # Send to the channel
            try:
                msg_caption = f"Trigger message:[{msg_og}]"
                await context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, photo=open(img_path, 'rb'), caption=msg_caption)
                await context.bot.delete_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, message_id=update.channel_post.message_id)
            except Exception as e2:
                await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="<ECHO>" + update.channel_post.text + ":: EXC:" + str(e2))
                print("  on_chat() EXC2:" + str(e2))
            del img_name
            del img_path
        else:
            print("  on_chat() Ignoring message:" + msg_og)
    except Exception as e:
        print("  on_chat() EXC:" + str(e))
        return False
    return True


async def main1():
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(C_TELEGRAM_LOGIN_TOKEN).build()
    chat_handler = MessageHandler(filters.ALL, on_chat)
    application.add_handler(chat_handler)
    print("Telegram bot initialized, will start polling now.")

    vid_read_thread = Thread(target=start_reading_frames)
    vid_read_thread.start()
    async with application:
        await application.initialize()
        await application.updater.initialize()
        await application.start()
        await application.updater.start_polling()
        print("called application.start()")
        while is_video_capture_on:
            time.sleep(0.5)
        await application.updater.stop_polling()
        await application.stop()
        print("called application.stop()")


def main2():
    vid_read_thread = Thread(target=start_reading_frames)
    vid_read_thread.start()

    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(C_TELEGRAM_LOGIN_TOKEN).build()
    chat_handler = MessageHandler(filters.ALL, on_chat)
    application.add_handler(chat_handler)
    application.run_polling()
    # print("alok-telegram-bot.py END")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    is_video_capture_on = True
    # asyncio.run(main1())
    main2()
```

Comment: I take it `cv2's imread and imshow loop` is a placeholder? Can you provide a full MWE? I think this is the crucial part.

Comment: I tried the  `cv2's imread and imshow loop` in two ways - one by starting a threading.Thread and one by directly launching it on main thread. In both cases, video capture is starting fine. Also getting the print for `print("called application.start()")`

Comment: Added full source-code (minus imports and constants) - because I do not know what MWE is 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.sleep` is blocking (in the asyncio sense), i.e. it doesn't allow asyncio code to be executed in the background. Try replacing it with [`await asyncio.sleep(0.5)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=asyncio%20sleep#asyncio.sleep).

Comment: Perfect! Coming  from Java background, I guess that this is more like `wait()` and `notify()` rather than `Thread.sleep()`. Is that it? Thanks a lot anyway!